# .NET: Value type inheritance - technical limitations?

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, internals, value-type

I'm wondering if there are any technical reasons for why .NET value types do not support inheritance (disregarding interface implementation)... I can't at first glance think of a reason why value types shouldn't allow single base class inheritance.

(I mean, arguably, inheritance for value types would be bad if you end up with a huge inheritance hierarchy, but I'm mostly wondering if there are any runtime limitations rather than practical limitations.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider the memory allocated for a value type. The CLR knows exactly how much space to allocate for a variable of a value type, because it knows what fields there will be. It can't possibly end up with a subtype value with more fields.

Now we *could* have value type inheritance which just truncated things:

```
ExtendedValueType evt = new ExtendedValueType(...);
BaseValueType bvt = evt;
// Now you couldn't cast back to ExtendedValueType, because we'd have lost
// information
```

Likewise there's nowhere for type information to live in the value itself, so any virtual methods overridden by the extended type wouldn't be called via `bvt`, because as far as everything is concerned, the value is then *just* a value of `BaseValueType`. In other words, a lot of "natural" inheritance features would be missing in a way which I think would cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: Ah, that certainly makes sense. On the type information note, how does .GetType() on a value type work then, though? Does that just work trivially since ValueType and Object are guaranteed to not have fields?

Comment: @Zor: It boxes the value, and then calls `GetType` on that. Boxing knows the type, because the relevant storage location is statically typed to be the exact value type. Ironically, that means you can get a `NullReferenceException` even on a value type, if it's a nullable value type with a null value :)

Answer (score 7):

I believe the reason why value types do not support inheritance is due to how they are represented in memory. The size of and consequently the data represented by a value type is dependent on its constituent fields. That is, if your value type contains an int and a string, the total size on a 32 bit system would be 8, or 4 (size of int) + 4 (size of pointer). What this means is that  value types are represented in memory are a block of bytes, without any more information.

Now contrast that with class types, they are all size of pointers, or 4 on 32 bit systems. Since instances of class types are pointers, they can then refer to the things you need for inheritance, like a VMT (virtual method table) and a reference to the parent classes information. This is something a value type can't do, and hence why value types don't support inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose it could be done.

You would be able to re-use some implementation.
But the real benefits of inheritance are Substitution and Polymorphism. They require use-by-reference.

And that is why interface implementation *is* supported because it always involves Boxing. But that would not do for inheritance.

Comment: Interface implementation on value types doesn't *always* involve boxing. You can use an interface as a generic constraint on a value-type and then call its methods without boxing.